# NSDATA to PNG file

Tags: ios, objective-c, png, nsdata

EHi i use this code to convert image to NSData:

```
NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[Defs documentsPathForFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",UserName]]];
```

How can i convert back NSData to PNG and store it as file at directory?

P.S. 
I used this code after i receive the uint8_t bytes from BLE but no file created and not error msg:

```
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:pngArr length:pngArrIndex];
                            NSError *error = nil;
                            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                            NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
                            NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_rec.png",UserName]]; //Add the file name
                            [imageData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]; //Write the file
                            NSLog(@"Write returned error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

***UPDATE***

But if i use this code after PNG to NSData conversion it creates the PNG photo file.

Both arrays are same.

Comment: UIImage *convertedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData]

Comment: I need to store it to file.

Comment: if you need to store need to store an image available with you into a file, you can try [imageData writeToFile: atomically:]

Comment: I convert The original png and send it to other device, it receives the same array of bytes but cannot create png file.

on the original device i can create Png from converted NSData.

Comment: May be you wish add this image in the Camera roll?

Comment: i just need to save it to file.

Comment: as @MithunMadhav mentionned, use writeToFile: which is available in NSData.